# Conditionally replace values in multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There has been a few other questions regarding replacing values in multidimensional array on here, but I didn't find anything regarding what I was trying to do, exactly, per se.

I have an array that I get from an API and I need to update a few values based on other values in the array tree before sending the API payload to the browser.

In the array when the `sale[0] === true` I am looking for some logic to then replace the `[price][0]` value with a corresponding new sale price.

Using the `foreach`, I can easily loop through the each of the nodes in the array, but I am unsure once I loop through the array, how I can update the original array with new price if/when sale node === true.

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [results] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [items] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 846471605959
                                                        )

                                                    [title] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Test Item 846471605959
                                                        )

                                                    [imageURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/images/846471605959.jpg
                                                        )

                                                    [itemURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/item/846471605959
                                                        )


                                                    [price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 799.00
                                                        )

                                                    [sale] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => true
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 414953260545
                                                        )

                                                    [title] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Test Item 414953260545
                                                        )

                                                    [imageURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/images/414953260545.jpg
                                                        )

                                                    [itemURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/item/414953260545
                                                        )


                                                    [price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 199.00
                                                        )

                                                    [sale] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => false
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 684865199812
                                                        )

                                                    [title] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Test Item 684865199812
                                                        )

                                                    [imageURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/images/684865199812.jpg
                                                        )

                                                    [itemURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/item/684865199812
                                                        )


                                                    [price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 699.00
                                                        )

                                                    [sale] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => false
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [3] => Array

                                                (
                                                    [id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 987800965761
                                                        )

                                                    [title] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Test Item 987800965761
                                                        )

                                                    [imageURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/images/987800965761.jpg
                                                        )

                                                    [itemURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/item/987800965761
                                                        )

                                                    [price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 499.00
                                                        )

                                                    [sale] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => true
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [4] => Array

                                                (
                                                    [id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 005457536677
                                                        )

                                                    [title] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Test Item 005457536677
                                                        )

                                                    [imageURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/images/005457536677.jpg
                                                        )

                                                    [itemURL] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://foo/bar/item/005457536677
                                                        )

                                                    [price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 99.00
                                                        )

                                                    [sale] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => false
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                }

        )

)
```

Comment: "I didn't find anything regarding what I was trying to do, exactly" Do you really have to find something that exactly matches? Can't you learn general principles?

Comment: Use reference variables in your `foreach` loop. Then you can update the current element and it will modify the original array.

Comment: Is there a reason why the leaf elements are arrays? Can they have more than 1 element in them?

Comment: @Barmar - I guess, literally speaking, no, but even from a generality perspective, I didn't really see anything that I *thought* was applicable to my scenario.

Edit: Yes, the leaf elements can have more than one element to them, I just a much condensed version for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference variable for the `foreach` iteration variable, then you can update the element in place.

```
foreach $data['response'][0]['results'][0]['items'] as &$item) {
    if ($item['sale'][0]) {
        $item['price'][0] = $new_price;
    }
}
```

If you also need to loop through all the elements in the `sale` array, add a nested loop.

```
foreach $data['response'][0]['results'][0]['items'] as &$item) {
    foreach ($item['sale'] as $i => $sale) {
        if ($sale) {
            $item['price'][$i] = $new_price;
        }
    }
}
```